# Firebase CLI not detecting NextJS Framework on hosting init

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

Im trying to run `firebase init hosting` on the root folder of my NextJS repo but it doesn't seems to detect the framework and continue to asks me for the build directory.

firebase version 11.15.0
node version v16.13.2
next version ^12.2.2

Any idea if this is a bug or i might be missing something?

I was checking the firebase CLI here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/200ee7e8d7d62e6ff1c05e96cb120aabff02c237/src/frameworks/next/index.ts#L54 but wasnt able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run command `firebase experiments:enable webframeworks` first.

It's missing in the docs, reported issue
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5152